# Do 6-year limits for junior professors in Germany include time abroad?

Tags: germany

This question follows up on a [recent related question regarding Junior professor positions in Germany](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/197426/junior-professorships-w1-in-germany-does-the-6-year-limit-before-start-apply).

The rule-of-thumb is that Junior professor positions are given to people who haven't worked more than six years in academia, beginning with their PhD.

How do academic positions enter here? Let's say you have spent six years abroad, will that exclude you from being eligible to a Junior professor position?

Comment: As far as I understand, this is handled differently in different universities. So my guess would be that nobody can tell you. But I might be wrong.